# b-table v-slot actions not displaying anything

Tags: bootstrap-vue

This is my bootstrap vue table :

```
 <b-table :items="holidays " @row-clicked="updateItem">
    <template v-slot:cell(actions)="row">
        <b-button>
            <i class="fe fe-eye"></i>
        </b-button>
    </template>
</b-table>
```

No actions column is displayed, no button is displayed, template is not working .

This is my holidays data format :

```
Array [ {"id":1,"blabla":"blabla"..etc ...}, {…} ]
```

The table is correctly displayed, but no button nor actions column is visible.
Do I have to create an "actions" sql column to make it work ?

This is my bootstrap vue version :  `"bootstrap-vue": "^2.19.0"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When only providing `<b-table>` with items, it will create columns based on they properties found in the first object. If you want a column that does not exist in your data you will need to use the `fields` prop and define what fields (columns) your table should have.

In your case you will need to fine a `actions` field, in addition to the other data you want displayed.

You can find more info on the [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#custom-data-rendering)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
          age: 40,
          first_name: 'Dickerson',
          last_name: 'Macdonald'
        },
        {
          age: 21,
          first_name: 'Larsen',
          last_name: 'Shaw'
        },
        {
          age: 89,
          first_name: 'Geneva',
          last_name: 'Wilson'
        },
        {
          age: 40,
          first_name: 'Thor',
          last_name: 'MacDonald'
        },
        {
          age: 29,
          first_name: 'Dick',
          last_name: 'Dunlap'
        }
      ],
      fields: [
        'age',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'actions' // this is a virtual column, that does not exist in our `items`
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.18.1/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />

<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.18.1/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
    <template #cell(actions)>
      <b-button variant="primary">Edit</b-button>
      <b-button variant="danger">Delete</b-button>
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot Hiws, your answer is so perfect ! Thank you !